# Build Xamarin android app in TeamCity using mac OS build agent

Tags: android, xamarin, xbuild

I am trying to make a build: `xbuild /t:SignAndroidPackage /p:Configuration=Release /p:AndroidSdkDirectory=/Users/administrator/Library/Android/sdk MyApp/Droid/MyApp.Droid.csproj` , but got errors:

```
/Users/administrator/Documents/teamcityagent/work/f540e07669d97f37/GoBounce/Droid/obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/library_project_imports/res/values-v24/values-v24.xml(2): error APT0000:  Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
/Users/administrator/Documents/teamcityagent/work/f540e07669d97f37/GoBounce/Droid/obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/library_project_imports/res/values-v24/values-v24.xml(2): error APT0000:  Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
```

I've tried different options for Application properties, but result still the same

[image]

On Mac installed several android SDK versions: 15,19,21,23,24,26 and several android SDK build tools.

The strangest thing is that I could open source code downloaded by TC agent in XamarinStudio and build project without any problem, but in TC I got this annoying error. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to change Target Framework to Android 7

Comment: Ive tried change to A7, change all to 24 SDK, A6 and so on - that doesnt help.